# builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Why does it give this error? I have a list of list b and I want to subtract c from the last element of the first list of b.

```
sofar = abs(b[len(b[0])-1] - c)
```

Comment: You should include a minimal example of your data. Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: If `b` is a list of lists, then `b[n]` is a list.  `-` isn't defined for a list.

Answer (score 0):

The last element of the first list in the list-of-lists `b` is (no need for `len(LIST) - 1`, `-1` will get the last element just fine):

```
b[0][-1]
```

You can see that from:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]         # Three lists.
>>> y = [4,5,6]
>>> z = [7,8,9,10,11]
>>> b = [x,y,z]         # List of lists, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11]].
>>> b[0][-1]            # Voilà ...
3
```

And you can modify it with a simple:

```
>>> b[0][-1] += 10
>>> b
[[1, 2, 13], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
#       ^^
#       Has had 10 added to it.
```

What *you* have, `b[len(b[0])-1]`, is the *list* `b[something]`, where `something` is the index of the last item in `b[0]`. That's why it's complaining about trying to subtract an integer from a list.